# Overriding virtual methods when instantiating a class

Tags: c#

I have a class with some virtual functions, let's pretend this is one of them:

```
public class AClassWhatever
{
    protected virtual string DoAThingToAString(string inputString)
    {
        return inputString + "blah";
    } 
}
```

I want to instantiate this class while overriding "DoAThingToAString" inline, much like I can declare properties inline in a declaration, as follows:

```
...

AClassWhatever instance = new AClassWhatever
{
    DoAThingToAString = new function(string inputString)
    {
        return inputString + inputString + " fill my eyes."
    }
}

...
```

And now for "instance", DoAThingToAString is overridden with that definition. I need to be able to define the default behavior in the class definition and only override it as needed, differently different times, and I don't want to proliferate a bunch of subclasses to do this.

I know I need to use delegates or something similar, but I've been out of the syntax game for way too long and google was giving me too much irrelevant info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use delegates or `Func`s to do this.

First, add this to your `AClassWhatever` class:

```
public Func<string, string> DoAThingToAString = (x) => x + "blah";
```

Now you can use the same syntax to override the action.

```
AClassWhatever instance = new AClassWhatever()
{
    DoAThingToAString = (x) => x + x + " fill my eyes."
};
```

Comment: This is the syntax I was looking for, but stupid question.  In DoAThingToAString, I am using a controller extension method that is called from a controller action as such:

    `this.DoExtensionMethod(someString);`

I no longer have a reference to "this" now that I am inside the Func definition.  Is there a way to get a reference to the caller, or must I pass it in along with my other input?

Comment: @kamii, You will have to pass in a reference to the object, or any other specific values you need. This is an anonymous function, so it has no idea of the instance. (please fact check me).

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it with methods, but you could do the equivalent with delegates / anonymous methods:

```
public class AClassWhatever
{
    public AClassWhatever()
    {
        this.DoAThingToAString = this.DoAThingToAStringImpl;
    }

    public Func<string, string> DoAThingToAString { get; set; }

    protected virtual string DoAThingToAStringImpl(string input)
    {
        return input + input + " fill my eyes.";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var instance = new AClassWhatever
{
    DoAThingToAString = inputString => inputString + inputString +
        " fill my eyes something other than the default behavior."
}

var result = instance.DoAThingToAString("input");
```

Note that `inputString => inputString + inputString + "..."` is the same as `x => x + x + "..."`

Comment: "I need to be able to define the default behavior in the class definition..."

Comment: @mellamokb I changed my answer to provide a default implementation in the constructor.

Comment: I'm giving you the answer due to better coding, but perhaps you have an answer to the reference-to-caller question I asked gunr2171 in comments?

Comment: @kamii rather than using the this pointer, just use the reference itself.

Comment: @Dan, I think his question is that, when overloading the function, he will not be able to use private members of his instance variable from within the function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not define a delegate property and use that definition if it exists when the method is called?  In your instantiation of the object, you can provide an alternate definition using the property.

For example:

```
public MyDelegateTypeThatMatchesMyFunctionCall DoAThingToAStringProperty { get; set; }

public class AClassWhatever
{
    protected virtual string DoAThingToAString(string inputString)
    {
        var handler = this.DoAThingToAStringProperty;
        if (handler)
        {
            return handler(inputString);
        }

        // do default behavior
        return inputString + "blah";
    } 
}
```

If you want to ensure that your delegate property overrides any overridden definition of the virtual method you could do it like this:

```
public MyDelegateTypeThatMatchesMyFunctionCall DoAThingToAStringProperty { get; set; }

public class AClassWhatever
{
    protected string DoAThingToAString(string inputString)
    {
        var handler = this.DoAThingToAStringProperty;
        if (handler)
        {
            return handler(inputString);
        }

        // do default behavior
        return DoAThingToAStringInternal(inputString);
    } 

    protected virtual string DoAThingToAStringInternal(string inputString)
    {
        // do default behavior
        return inputString + "blah";
    } 
}
```